# How do to link all of my methods to my client correctly

Tags: java, arrays, class, parameters, client

I am continuing my last project in my Java Intro class. I made a class file of GradeBook to display the calculating methods. I am having trouble cleaning up my GradeBookClient, for I had to cheat and put in variables when making my objects from my class. MY teacher then emailed me saying I needed to create two identical arrays to test my **.equals method** in my client. How do I make two new arrays?. So my main objectives are to **create two arrays to test my equals method, and to figure out how to make my objects with parameters I already have.**

My *.equals* method from Class file:

```
public boolean equals( Object a )
   {
      if ( !( a instanceof GradeBook ) )
         return false;
      else
      {
         GradeBook objGB = ( GradeBook ) a;

         if ( gradeBook.length != objGB.gradeBook.length )
            return false;

         for ( int i = 0; i <= gradeBook.length - 1; i++ )
         {
            if ( gradeBook[i] != objGB.gradeBook[i] )
               return false;
         }
         return true;
      }
   }

}
```

Client Page:

```
public class GradeBookClient
{
   public static GradeBook classRoom1, classRoom2;
   public static int astudents;
   public static void main( String [] args )
   {  


      astudents = 100;
      classRoom1 = new GradeBook (astudents);
      System.out.println( "The class size is " + classRoom1.getStudent() + " students." + "\n" + classRoom1.toString() ); 

      astudents = 100;
      classRoom2 = new GradeBook (astudents);
      System.out.println( "The class size is " + classRoom2.getStudent() + " students." + "\n" + classRoom2.toString() );

      if ( classRoom1.equals( classRoom2 ))
      System.out.println("Classroom 1 has the same grades and class size as Classroom 2.");
      else
      System.out.println("Classroom 1 and Classroom 2 have different grades and class sizes.");
   }
}
```

The part where I cheated was when I put astudents = 100 to fill in the parameter for my objects. My Constructor is below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GradeBook {

   int[] gradeBook;
   int student;
   int MINgrade = 0;
   int MAXgrade = 100;

//default constructor
   public GradeBook()
   {
      student = 0;
      gradeBook = new int [student];
   }

//constructor
   public GradeBook(int student1)
   {
      student = student1;
   //instantiate array with same length as parameter
      gradeBook = new int[student];

      for ( int i = 0; i <= gradeBook.length-1; i++ )
      {
         gradeBook[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
      }
      Arrays.sort(gradeBook);

   }
```

Comment: Your teacher probably wants `equals` to return `true`. As it is you are creating 2 arrays with random values. They will most likely be different. Try initializing with `gradeBook[i] = i`

Comment: She told me to make an array of grades randomly generated, then make two new arrays to test the equals method. Where do you want me to make the edit you suggested? in my Constructor?

Comment: Then you need to change your constructor to accept the array and copy them.

Comment: in my parameters of the constructor right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your constructor to:

```
 public GradeBook(int[] grades)
 {
      //instantiate array with same length as parameter
      gradeBook = new int[grades.length];

      for ( int i = 0; i <= gradeBook.length-1; i++ )
      {
         gradeBook[i] = grades[i];
      }
   }
```

In your `main` create the random array with the code you had and pass that to the constructor.

```
public static void main( String [] args )
{  
  int[] grades = new int[100];

  for (int i=0; i<grades.length; i++)
  {
     grades[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
  }

  classRoom1 = new GradeBook(grades);
  System.out.println( "The class size is " + classRoom1.getStudent() + " students." + "\n" + classRoom1.toString() ); 

  classRoom2 = new GradeBook(grades);
  System.out.println( "The class size is " + classRoom2.getStudent() + " students." + "\n" + classRoom2.toString() );

  if ( classRoom1.equals( classRoom2 ))
  System.out.println("Classroom 1 has the same grades and class size as Classroom 2.");
  else
  System.out.println("Classroom 1 and Classroom 2 have different grades and class sizes.");
}
```

Comment: You create the random array in your `main`

Comment: Your teacher wants you to validate the `equals` method. For that, you need to test two different objects whose values are 'equal'. In your first try, you created 2 objects that were not equal.

Comment: Oh wow, my webpage did not update, you put the main under the edits, thanks man.

Comment: You'll also need to change the `getStudent()` method to return `gradeBook.length` or initialize `student` with that value in your constructor.

Comment: OH yeah I have to because now it is saying my student size is equal to 0